# ADF Dynamic file naming for BLOB through Data flow and then into a copy activity to SQLDB

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am using the primary answer here. ([How do I pull the last modified file with data flow in azure data factory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74629505/how-do-i-pull-the-last-modified-file-with-data-flow-in-azure-data-factory)) My data flow kicks back errors that look like a mapping error in data flow. :( Is there a fix for this? It's a complex json mapping flow that takes a json and creates a CSV.

[image]

[image]

I was expecting it to run, but it didn't.

```
    source(output(
        {$schema} as string,
        type as string,
        items as (type as string, properties as (columns as (type as string, items as (type as string)[]), rows as (type as string, items as (type as string, items as (type as string)[])[])), required as string[])[]
    ),
    allowSchemaDrift: true,
    validateSchema: false,
    ignoreNoFilesFound: false,
    purgeFiles: true,
    modifiedAfter: (toTimestamp(1679961600000L)),
    documentForm: 'arrayOfDocuments') ~> source1
source1 select(mapColumn(
        columns
    ),
    skipDuplicateMapInputs: true,
    skipDuplicateMapOutputs: true) ~> select1
source1 derive(rows = unfold(rows)) ~> derivedColumn1
derivedColumn1 derive(rows = replace(replace(toString(rows),'[',''),']','')) ~> derivedColumn2
select1 derive(columns = replace(replace(toString(columns),'[',''),']','')) ~> derivedColumn3
derivedColumn2 rank(asc(rows, true),
    caseInsensitive: true,
    output(id as long),
    dense: true) ~> rank1
rank1 select(mapColumn(
        rows,
        id
    ),
    skipDuplicateMapInputs: true,
    skipDuplicateMapOutputs: true) ~> select2
select2, select3 union(byName: false)~> union1
union1 sort(asc(id, true)) ~> sort1
derivedColumn3 aggregate(groupBy(columns),
    column = first(columns)) ~> aggregate1
aggregate1 select(mapColumn(
        column
    ),
    skipDuplicateMapInputs: true,
    skipDuplicateMapOutputs: true) ~> select3
sort1 select(mapColumn(
        rows
    ),
    skipDuplicateMapInputs: true,
    skipDuplicateMapOutputs: true) ~> select4
select4 sink(allowSchemaDrift: true,
    validateSchema: false,
    skipDuplicateMapInputs: true,
    skipDuplicateMapOutputs: true) ~> DS2csv
```

Comment: Can you provide what configurations you have used in the above `select1`, `derivedColumn1` and `derivedColumn3`. Try adding the entire dataflow json as it might be easier to understand.

Comment: The schema is the problem here. I think you have the `columns and rows` inside items field. Check if the below solution helps. If not, try to extract the 2 columns, rows and columns from the source before applying the other transformations. You can edit the question to provide how exactly your json file looks like if the below solution didn't help.

Comment: Agreed, I got it running again and part of the problem was the API pull I had it linked too. Gremlins had tinkered with the API pull and changed the auto updating source file. :) Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I have taken the sample data provided in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75861119/complex-json-in-adf-that-has-me-scratching-my-head).

[image]

- The error occurs because of the schema of the source data. I have got the same error when I used the transformations provided.

[image]

- When you look at the schema of the source, you can see that the schema does not include either `rows` or `columns` columns. And hence reference to these columns in `select1, derivedColumn1 and derivedColumn3` is throwing an error.

[image]

- When I import schema, the new schema would be as shown below:

[image]

- The dataflow would work fine now since the columns `rows and columns` are included in the schema.  The sink data preview would be as shown below:

[image]

- After running the dataflow, the file generated would be as shown below:

[image]